# TypeError: data type not understood while creating a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Having a list of boolean conditions list I would like to generate a matrix with the lists that have False or True values

For this example 
    `values = [[True, False], [False], [True], [True, False]]`
the result will be

```
    False  True
0   1       1
1   1       0
2   0       1
3   1       1
```

I tried to do that as following:

```
nodes = [True, False]
values = [[True, False], [False], [True], [True, False]]
res = np.array([[int(cond in vals) for vals in values] for cond in nodes],
                dtype=[(node, int) for node in nodes])
```

But I am getting the error `TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: what is the `dtype` suppose to represent?  I thought it just needed to be `int` to specify that each value in the array is an `int`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen it represent `res` values type.

Comment: let np.array analyse your data : In [348]: array( [[True, False], [False], [True], [True, False]])  ->
Out[348]: array([[True, False], [False], [True], [True, False]], dtype=object)

Comment: have you tried `dtype=int`? I think that is all you need for this to work...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yeah that works with `dtype=int` thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `dtype=int`, and then we have,

```
import numpy as np 

nodes = [True, False]
values = [[True, False], [False], [True], [True, False]]
res = np.array([[cond in vals for vals in values] for cond in nodes], dtype=int)

print(res)
# Output
[[1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1]]
```

Comment: when the `dtype` is specified you don't even need to explicitly cast to that same type, so `int(cond in vals)` is a bit redundant, it could just be `cond in vals`